# Is it OK to clean up your "favorites" list every once in awhile?

Tags: support, bookmarks

Everyday I find at least a few awesome questions that I end up favoriting. Every few months or so, I tend to go back to these questions using the "favorites" section on my profile page. What always happens is that I find a handful of questions that I feel I no longer find interesting enough to be in my "favorites" section so I unfavorite them.

My question: **is such behavior appropriate**?

Comment: Why would it not be OK? o_o

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is  appropriate. Your list of favorites is essentially a publicly shared list of your bookmarks, somewhat similar to [Delicious](https://delicious.com/). You manage them as you see fit.